# Jquery - Windows Load how to keep longer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one simple questions i want to keep longer to show but what i try not working. i making something wrong probably.

My part of html

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">
        <p class="center-text">
            test <br>test <img src="images/myemail.gif">
            <em>test</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js my part

```js
// JavaScript Document
(function ($) {

$(window).load(function() { 
 $("#status").fadeOut(); 
 $("#preloader").delay(400).fadeOut("medium");
});

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
 <div id="status">
     <p class="center-text">
   test<br>test<img src="images/myemail.gif">
            <em>test</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to keep more longer preloader and status after load. I was settimeout or add to hide and show ready functions but nothing change it

Thank you

Comment: increase `delay` time.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi that metod is not working :(

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish. You're fading out `div#status` immediately on load - do you want it to remain visible for a while before fading it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used fade out for `div#status`, the `div#preloader` still there but you didn't see any after `div#status` fade out.
I suggest you should

```
$(window).load(function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  //$("#status").fadeOut();
  $("#preloader").fadeOut("medium");
 }, 400);
});
```

Comment: That is fix my problem. I was have cloudflare cache also about that why my setTimeout not working i understand after you write this i close cloudflare and try again :) thank you much

Comment: Its better to have a setTimeout assigned to variable and then in future destroy it in case needed

    var myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {}, 50);

    clearTimeout(myTimeout);

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `div#preloader` to remain on screen for longer, then just remove the fade out of `div#status`:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $("#preloader").delay(400).fadeOut("medium");
});
```